# NoMethodError in controller#new(Forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been trying to create a form on a page, with an instance variable @next, but it doesn't seem to work. When I remove the part which includes the form, the page opens up, clearly depicting that the paths have been correctly mentioned in routes.rb. To be clear,i haev added the following method in the controller file

```
def new
@next=Self.new
end
```

The part where  form is created.

```
<%= form_for(@next) do |a| %>
<%= a.text_field_tag :name %>
<%= a.text_field_tag :prof %>
<%= a.text_field_tag :pic, :placeholder => 'Enter address' %>
```

i m using Rails 4.0.2

routes.rb

```
get '/worms' => 'worms#index'
get '/worms/new' => 'worms#new'
post '/worms' => 'worms#create'
get '/worms/:id' => 'worms#show'
```

Please help.

Comment: is your model called `Self`?

Comment: Can you please post your routes file?

Comment: What is your model name?

Comment: in controller you can't call self. Self is used in  a class.
So you can write self in you model/class, and in controller you have to write ModelName.new.

Comment: yes, my model is called Self.

Comment: to be clear, 'worms' is the name of my controller...

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be look like this as below...

Self means what ?, You should write the name of your model here.

And If you need full CRUD operation on the same then write the below line for the routes...

```
resources :your-model-name-in-plural

<%= form_for @next do |a| %>
<%= a.text_field :name %>
<%= a.text_field :prof %>
<%= a.text_field :pic, :placeholder => 'Enter address' %>
```